# How to make Apache "sleep" for a few seconds

Tags: perl, apache

I want my server to **stop for a few seconds** and then start again.
I am trying to use `sleep(5)`.
Will this help?

I've tried with a **Perl** script containing:

```
if($mech=~ m/(Connection refused)/) {print "SLEEPING\n";sleep(5);redo;}
```

Comment: Might I ask where did you put the "sleep(5)" into ?

Comment: if($mech=~ m/\(Connection refused\)/)
    {print "SLEEPING\n";sleep(5);redo;}

Comment: I have tried doing this.If "Connection Refused " is matched in my $mech then Apache should go to sleep for 5seconds and then start again.

Comment: Where do you have $mech from? You send Apache "to sleep" via `/etc/init.d/apache2 stop` but this is not a good idea in general, because you lose all current and ongoing connections too...

Comment: using WWW::Mechanize and a url

Comment: can anyone show me an example of how to pause for one second in Perl? I am trying the sleep command and it isn't working.

Comment: Please append to your question: **What is your goal by sending Apache to sleep**

Comment: I think the user has confused the words server with client and Apache with Perl. It appears the user is trying to make a connection using WWW::Mechanize but wanting to retry after a sleep if the connection fails.

Comment: OK.what I am trying to do is that if my $mech contains "Connection Refused" then ,I want my script to stop execution for a few seconds and then restart again.So,I now think that instead of making the Apache sleep ,I should rather make my perl script sleep for a few secondsand then start again

Comment: YES PP is right.Thats what I am trying to do .If a connection is not getting established ,I want my perl script to retry getting connected after a gap of 5 seconds

Answer (score 0):

A server hosts web pages. A client connects to a server. A Perl script using WWW::Mechanize is a *client*.

I suspect you're trying to do the following:

```
my $retries = 3;
my $resp; # response goes here
while ( $retries-- > 0 ) {
    $resp = $ua->get( "http://www.google.com/" );
    if ( ! $resp->is_success ) {
        warn( "Failed to get webpage: " . $resp->status_line );
        sleep( 5 );
        next; # continue the while loop
    }

    last; # success!
}

if ( $retries == 0 ) {
    die( "Too many retries!" );
}

# old versions of LWP::UserAgent didn't have decoded_content()
my $content = $resp->can('decoded_content') ? 
    $resp->decoded_content : $resp->content;

print( $content );
```

**UPDATE**

Here is the code you supplied in a comment:

```
use WWW::Mechanize;
my $mech = new WWW::Mechanize;
eval {
    $mech->get($url);
}; 
if($@) { 
    print STDERR "Burst\n";
    print STDERR Dumper($mech);
    # my $var=$mech;
    # print STDERR "var $var\n";
    # if($mech=~ m/(Connection refused)/) 
    # {
    #     print "SLEEPING\n";
    #     sleep(5);
    #     redo;
    # }
```

From `perdoc -f redo`:

> The "redo" command restarts the loop block without evaluating the conditional again.  The "continue" block, if any, is not executed.  If the LABEL is omitted, the command refers to the innermost enclosing loop.

Seeing as you haven't put your code in a loop the call to `redo` doesn't have any effect.

Comment: use WWW::Mechanize;my $mech = new WWW::Mechanize;
  
eval{$mech->get($url);};
if($@)
{
 print STDERR Dumper($mech);
    if($mech=~ m/\(Connection refused\)/)
    {print "SLEEPING\n";sleep(5);redo;}                                                                                                                                this is what I am trying to do

Comment: use WWW::Mechanize;
my $mech = new WWW::Mechanize;
eval {
    $mech->get($url);
}; 
if($@) { 
    print STDERR "Burst\n";
    print STDERR Dumper($mech);
    
     if($mech=~ m/(Connection refused)/) 
     {
        print "SLEEPING\n";
        sleep(5);
         redo;
     }}                                                               here is my edited code..will sleep work like the I have used it